# MySQL stopped working - Error 2002 - Unknown Instance

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sql-server

MySQL server was installed and was running just fine.  Today we can't connect to the database via our websites.  Command line access using `mysql -u username -p` also fails.  Finally, phpmyadmin fails.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance:
start: Job failed to start
```

Error logs (/var/log/mysql/error.log & /var/log/mysql.err & /var/log/mysql.log) are all empty for the past week.  The problem just began today.

I have looked at lots of answers including [Ubuntu Error 2002 “Can't connect to local MySql server through socket…”](https://serverfault.com/questions/327551/ubuntu-error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket) and [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL](https://serverfault.com/questions/106571/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql).

Should I just reinstall mysql server and chalk it up as an unknown error?  (horrible idea, obviously).

**What is the right course of action to fix immediately and prevent from reoccurring?**

Comment: have you tried killing off any existing mysql processes with **kill**, and deleting the files under `/var/run/mysqld`?  Or maybe rebooting?

Comment: Rebooting did not help.  I have not tried kill nor delete.  One more point... I need to maintain all mysql databases and data.

Comment: Can you post the result of `ps aux | grep mysql`?

Comment: Added to question

Comment: Indeed I missed that the service was not running. What about `sudo mysqld --verbose --log-error=mysqld.err`? Post any output and/or the content of the `mysqld.err` file. Check also `ls -l /var/lib/mysql` (don't post this) and make sure that all files are owned by `mysql` both as user and group.

Comment: Added to question.  Ownership is mysql:mysql

Comment: Make sure you are not out of diskspace. That could kill your mysql. Also, make sure your sock file is deleted. I think my.cnf will tell you where it creates the mysql.sock file.

Comment: Great points.  Diskspace was a concern but still had 10%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the bind-address from the IP to 127.0.0.1.  Still not sure why this worked and then all of a sudden stopped.  Here is the solution for others.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

change

```
bind-address = "127.0.0.1"
```

And then

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Just one question why you restarted apache2 after changing my.cnf file?

Comment: Edited - did not restart apache, restarted mysql.  Sorry about the typo.  It is corrected.

Comment: my bind address has always been set to `127.0.0.1` and this is a regular occurance on more than 1 of my servers.